# Canvas Animation Javascript reverse

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a top to bottom falling canvas animation, but I want to reverse it (go from bottom to top). I can't figure out how to change the direction

I have my code here

http://js.do/code/176399

sample:

```
  function Ember(x, y, s /*radius*/ , p /*num points*/ ) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.s = s;
  this.p = p;
  this.img = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = this.img.getContext('2d'),
    len = this.s / 1.45;
  this.img.height = this.img.width = this.s * 2;
  context.translate(this.s, this.s);
  context.rotate((Math.PI * 1 / 10));
  context.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    context.lineTo(0, -s);
    context.rotate((Math.PI * 2 / (p * 2)));
    context.lineTo(0, s);
    context.rotate((Math.PI * 2 / (p * 2)));
  }
  context.closePath();
  context.shadowBlur = this.s / 3;
  context.shadowColor = 'rgba(174, 12, 1, 0.9)';
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(133,80,33,.45)';
  context.fill();
}
```

Just need to reverse the "fall" to bottom to top.

**Update:
following off of Jared's suggestion**

Changed:

```
embers[i].y += embers[i].vy;
```

to:

```
embers[i].y -= embers[i].vy;
```

However, I only get one animation cycle would like to have it continually animate new embers on the screen

Comment: Your question was answered (and should get a tick), updating your question to ask a new question will not get an answer. If you have another question ask in another post

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this line where you update the ember's Y position:

```
 embers[i].y = -embers[i].s;
```

Try changing this to something like this:

```
  embers[i].y = embers[i].s;
```

Comment: hi, yeah that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Jared, thanks it was 3 lines above that, that had to be changed. Thanks for making me take a 2nd look.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
function Ember(x, y, s /*radius*/ , p /*num points*/ ) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.s = s;
 this.p = p;
 this.img = document.createElement('canvas');
 var context = this.img.getContext('2d'),
  len = this.s / 1.45;
 this.img.height = this.img.width = this.s * 2;
 context.translate(this.s, this.s);
 context.rotate((Math.PI * 1 / 10));
 context.beginPath();
 for (var i = 0; i < p; i++) {
  context.lineTo(0, -s);
  context.rotate((Math.PI * 2 / (p * 2)));
  context.lineTo(0, s);
  context.rotate((Math.PI * 2 / (p * 2)));
 }
 context.closePath();
 context.shadowBlur = this.s / 3;
 context.shadowColor = 'rgba(174, 12, 1, 0.9)';
 context.fillStyle = 'rgba(133,80,33,.45)';
 context.fill();
}
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function () {
 return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function (callback) {
   window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };
})();
var canvas, context, height, width, embers;
setTimeout(init, 10);

function init() {
 canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 height = canvas.height = document.body.offsetHeight;
 width = canvas.width = document.body.offsetWidth;
 embers = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
  var x = Math.random() * width,
   y = Math.random() * height,
   s = Math.random() * 5 + 5,
   p = Math.random() * 8 + 8;
  var s = new Ember(x, y, s, p);
  s.vx = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  s.vy = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
  s.r = Math.random() * 360;
  embers.push(s);
 }

 update();
 render();
}


function update() {
 for (var i = 0, l = embers.length; i < l; i++) {
  embers[i].r += embers[i].vx / 10;
  embers[i].x += embers[i].vx;
  embers[i].y -= embers[i].vy;
  if (embers[i].y < 0) {
   embers[i].y = Math.random()*height;
   embers[i].vx = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
   embers[i].vy = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
  }
 }
 setTimeout(update, 1000 / 30);
}

function render() {
 context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
 for (var i = 0, l = embers.length; i < l; i++) {
  context.save();
  context.translate(embers[i].x, embers[i].y);
  context.rotate(embers[i].r);
  context.drawImage(embers[i].img, 0, 0);
  context.restore();
 }
 requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
</script>
```

Wrong if condition in update function, change it to check if v`(embers[i].y < 0)`, ans set appropriate new `y` position

```
if (embers[i].y < 0) {
        embers[i].y = Math.random()*height;
```